# How to remove column with ML.NET ColumnDropper

Tags: ml.net

Guys I'm new in machine learning and I'm trying to use Microsoft.ML and in particular Transform part of the framework.
Can you somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong. I cannot remove a column from my dataset?

```
var loader = new Microsoft.ML.Data.TextLoader(TrainDataPath).CreateFrom<BloodDonateData>(useHeader: true, separator: ',');
int columnsCount = 5;
using (var environment = new TlcEnvironment())
{
    Experiment experiment = environment.CreateExperiment();
    ILearningPipelineDataStep pipelineDataStep = loader.ApplyStep(null, 
    experiment) as ILearningPipelineDataStep;
    experiment.Compile();
    loader.SetInput(environment, experiment);
    experiment.Run();

    ColumnDropper columnDropper = new ColumnDropper
    {
        Column = new string[] { "Time" },
        Data = pipelineDataStep.Data
    };
    columnDropper.ApplyStep(pipelineDataStep, experiment);

    var data = experiment.GetOutput(columnDropper.Data);

    using (var cursor = data.GetRowCursor(a => true))
    {
       // print data..
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it giving an error or just doesn't work as expected?

Comment: It does not give me any error, it just does not remove selected column 'Time'.